# ignore files ending with numbers with 0-3 digits

Tags: git, gitignore

This question must have been asked before, but I was not able to find an answer.
I want to use `.gitignore` to ignore all of the following files:

```
dsmodelext.c
dsmodelext1.c
dsmodelext2.c
dsmodelext23.c
dsmodelext107.c
```

Currently I put four lines in my `.gitignore` file:

```
dsmodelext.c
dsmodelext[0-9].c
dsmodelext[0-9][0-9].c
dsmodelext[0-9][0-9][0-9].c
```

Is there a way to express the same on a single line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Gitignore takes it's syntax from](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) fnmatch/glob, [which is specified in man glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

There doesn't seem to be a way to indicate a certain number of characters need to be matched, like you could with the regular expression `dsmodelext[0-9]{0,3}.c`

You could decide to be lenient and just defined `dsmodelext*.c` to be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

given the files

```
dsmodelext.c
dsmodelext1.c
dsmodelext2.c
dsmodelext23.c
dsmodelext2x3.c
dsmodelext107.c
dsmodelext107foo.c
```

The glob pattern `dsmodelext*[0-9].c` would match

```
dsmodelext1.c
dsmodelext2.c
dsmodelext23.c
dsmodelext2x3.c
dsmodelext107.c
```

For some of these number usecases this is a good enough approximation.